# Querying "fid"s for executing a task in MyBB

Tags: php, task, mybb

The task below overwhelms my PHP skills. That's why I'm asking for help here.

In the MyBB forum, when registering, users must:

1. Provide a 5-digit invoice number.

The information is stored in the mybb_userfields table in the fid8 column.

2. Enter text (letters)

The information is stored in the mybb_userfields table in the fid10 column.

In a task (mentally ... the examples below do not work) should be processed as follows:

**A) with IF conditions?**

**(FID8)**

```
if (fid8 >= 1 && fid8 <= 49999) {
$query = $db->query("UPDATE mybb_users SET additionalgroups = '8,9'");
}
```

etc.

**B) with WHERE conditions?**

**FID8**

```
$query = $db->query("UPDATE mybb_users SET additionalgroups = '8,9' WHERE fid8 >= '1' && fid8 <= '49000'");
```

etc.

How do you have to define the fields "**fid8**" and "**fid10**" (and others) beforehand so that something can be done with the values ​​(see examples above)?

Many thanks in advance for tips and hints.
(Translate with Google Translater)

---

Solution (example):

```
$db->query("UPDATE mybb_users u LEFT JOIN mybb_userfields f ON f.ufid = u.uid SET usergroup = '4' WHERE f.fid8 = 'xxx'");
```

Thanks to ExiTuS on MyBB.de

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sorry, but with the best will in the world I don't know how to make my request more precise.